# Unix shell events?

Tags: unix, shell, passwords, prompt

Is there any way so that i can echo password when asked for in unix shell without use of external binaries ? Something like simple function triggered when password prompt is displayed

Comment: More information for clarification please. What exactly is classed as external binaries?

Comment: Please describe an example scenario of what you would like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: the usual shells, sh, ksh, csh, tcsh, bash do not have any hooks for you to hang actions on (OK, so bash2 has context sensitive tab-completion).

---

On the other hand. The shell is just a program. You can replace it. If you can really say what you want to do you can hack and existing shell or write a new one to get the desired behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of [Expect](http://expect.nist.gov/)?

Perhaps this falls in the "external binaries" category, but if it does, then your question needs clarification.

Comment: Can you clarify this question?

Comment: What is the controlling entity that will "echo" the password to another program?